# Create Multivariate Normal Distribution with Low-rank Standard Deviation in Teensorflow Probability

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

recently I am dealing with state space model. For the transition equation *x_t = Ax_{t-1} + W w_t*, the *w_t~N(0, I)* is a multivariate normal distribution and W is a (possibly drop-rank) noise matrix.

So I want to use `tfp.distributions.MultivariateNormalLinearOperator` to generate the a distribution object. For example, the state dimension is 6, W is 6x3 matrix, therefore, `MultivariateNormalLinearOperator(loc=tf.zeros([6,]), scale=W)` would raise Error when using `.sample()` because of incorrect dimension.

So I change to use `tfp.distributions.MultivariateNormalFullCovariance` with covariance matrix `W @ tf.transpose(W)`. However, the covariance matrix not a full rank matrix, thus positive semi-definite. The `NaN` samples happen when using `.sample()`. Is there any good method to solve this problem?